# Every time I press ENTER Microsoft Office Word the line becomes a heading 2, how to disable this?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

every time I want to add a new paragraph the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key creates a new heading, it's like H2 is default style instead of normal.

[image: image 1]

it jumps here when I press Enter

[image: image 2]

Comment: Try applying one of the style sets and see if this changes the result,

Comment: I'm sure things like this are not reserved for administrators. It is continuing a numbered list (outline style).

Answer (score 3):

Every style has a configuration called **Style for following paragraph** and each time you hit Enter (thus creating a new paragraph) it formats the new paragraph to that style. Mine is in portuguese, but you'll get the idea.

[image: Style Formatting - Style for following paragraph]

Check if it's not configured to set the new paragraph as some **Title** in your case and if so, change it to Normal style or any style you prefer.
You can do it by right clicking the style used to format the text "Iahko odprt ali zaprt..." of your example, choose modify and change **Style for following paragraph** to a normal style.